# Why do my code do not work when I alert('finished') after download a file in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

When I click  the button to download a file from controller,In this period which the server returns the file I want to disable the button,and after the file return,I want to enable the button.But in fact,my code do not work. The button seems always to be enabed.

**View:**

```
//disable the button
document.getElementById("downloadButton").disabled=true;
//download file    
window.location.href('@Url.Action("UserDetails", "GetFile")')
//enable the button
document.getElementById("downloadButton").disabled=false;
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult GetFile()
{
//Product a file may take more than one minute  
Return File(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/UserA/a.png"),"imge/png");
}
```

Comment: Is the reason that js or jquery is always default asynchronous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
document.getElementById("downloadButton").disabled=true;
//download file    
window.location.href('@Url.Action("UserDetails", "GetFile")')
//enable the button
document.getElementById("downloadButton").disabled=false;
```

When you call `window.location.href()` you are changing the location of the page. As far as the browser is concerned at that point, the page no longer 'exists'. Since you are downloading a file, it won't disappear - but the page has no way of knowing when/that your file has completed download, and it stops executing your Javascript at that point, anyway.

Comment: If I click the download button and still in the page,Can I realize this ideaof this idea:Fist disable the button or make the backgound grey,and after the server return the file to the client,give the client a notice(enable the button or clear the background)?